# Ways to get to know of key names inside a javascript object literal

Tags: javascript

declare a javascript object literal

```
var objA = {'keyA':'valA'}
```

in the console

```
objA
> Object {keyA: "valA"}
```

the object is not an array

```
objA[0]
> undefined
```

the only way I know to get key names is to cicle on the object

```
for (x in objA) {
    console.log(x);
}
> keyA
```

Do you know any other ways to get key names from object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like this

```
var objA = {'keyA':'valA'};
console.log(Object.keys(objA));
```

[Object.keys will not work on older versions of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility), so you can use a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop like this

```
var objA = {'keyA':'valA'}, keys = [];
for (var key in objA) {
    keys.push(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) do this:

```
var objA = { 'keyA': 'valA', 'foo': 'bar' };
Object.keys( objA ); // [ 'keyA', 'foo' ]
```

Note that this is [not supported on all browsers yet](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys) - but it is on the modern versions of the popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var keys = Object.keys(objA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys function is available in newer browsers:

```
var keys = Object.keys(objA);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys